# Stopping gradients updating weights of a [sub]network in an architecture

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, torch

I have an architecture as follow (built using nngraph):

```
require 'nn'
require 'nngraph'


input = nn.Identity()()
net1 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 5, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(5, 20, 4, 4))
net2 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(20, 5, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(5, 1, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())
net3 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 20, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(20, 40, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(40, 2, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())

output1 = net1(input)
output2 = net2(output1)
output3 = net3(output2)
gMod = nn.gModule({input}, {output1, output3})


target1 = torch.rand(20, 51, 51)
target2 = torch.rand(2, 49, 49)
target2[target2:gt(0.5)] = 1
target2[target2:lt(0.5)] = 0
-- Do a forward pass
out1, out2 = unpack(gMod:forward(torch.rand(1, 56, 56)))

cr1 = nn.MSECriterion()
cr1:forward(out1, target1)
gradient1 = cr1:backward(out1, target1)

cr2 = nn.BCECriterion()
cr2:forward(out2, target2)
gradient2 = cr2:backward(out2, target2)


-- Now update the weights for the networks
LR = 0.001
gMod:backward(input, {gradient1, gradient2})
gMod:updateParameters(LR)
```

I wonder:

1) How one can **stop** gradient2 update the weights for **net1**, and only contribute to updating the weights for **net2** and **net3**?

2) How is it possible to prevent **gradient2** update **net3** weights, but update other sub[network] weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problems. Below I post the relevant codes for each one:

**Question 1**:

This is a litte bit tricky but totally doable. If `net2`'s first layer weights are not supposed to get updated with **gradient2** one needs to modify the updateGradInput() function of the layer after that and make it output a zero tensor. This is done in the following code:

```
input = nn.Identity()()
net1 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 5, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(5, 20, 4, 4))
net2 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialFullConvolutionInputGrad0(20, 5, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(5, 1, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())
net3 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 20, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(20, 40, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(40, 2, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())

-- Modifying the updateGradInput function so that it will output a zeroed-out tensor at the first layer of net2
local tempLayer = net2:get(1)
function tempLayer:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
         self.gradInput:resizeAs(input):zero()
         return self.gradInput
end

output1 = net1(input)
output2 = net2(output1)
output3 = net3(output2)
gMod = nn.gModule({input}, {output1, output3})

-- Everything else is the same ...
```

**Question 2**:

```
input = nn.Identity()()
net1 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 5, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(5, 20, 4, 4))
net2 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(20, 5, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(5, 1, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())
net3 = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 20, 3, 3)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(20, 40, 4, 4)):add(nn.ReLU(true)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(40, 2, 3, 3)):add(nn.Sigmoid())

net3.updateParameters = function() end -- Doing this prevents net3 weights get updated during the backward pass since the updateParameters function has been over-ridden

output1 = net1(input)
output2 = net2(output1)
output3 = net3(output2)
gMod = nn.gModule({input}, {output1, output3})

-- Everything else is the same ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to stop back propagation on net1?

```
net1.updateGradInput = function(self, inp, out) end
net1.accGradParameters = function(self,inp, out) end
```

just place this code after `gradient1 = cr1:backward(out1, target1)` and it should work.

Comment: I did what you said, but I get the error `/home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nngraph/gmodule.lua:423: expecting the innode to be used only once`. The error occurs when doing `gMod:backward(input, {gradient1, gradient2})`. Do you have any references for this? I might need to read more on it.

Comment: Sorry, I never had this problem. Maybe to drop the learning rate to 0 or almost 0 on this net can work?